# What would happen if I specify march twice in CXXFLAGS?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

Lets say I add `-march=broadwell` to the CXXFLAGS and later something else appends `-march=native` what behaviour should I expect from the resulting code?

`/usr/bin/c++ ... -march=broadwell  -march=native -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -g -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/path.dir/file.cpp.o -c /path/common/file.cpp`

Comment: What does `c++ --version` output? Then go to compiler documentation and search for the behavior.

Comment: Usually just the last specified flag. You can use `-v` (or whatever the verbose mode is) to check

Comment: The last one sticks, although I don't see why one would knowingly do this.

Comment: @Mansoor: The question is tagged with "cmake" and provided example of the command line is very similar to one generated by CMake (e.g. suffix `.cpp.o` for object files). In CMake compiler flags have several sources (variables, properties). The asker probably wants to specify `-march` exactly for override previous setting of the option.

Comment: Setting the flag from Cmake did the trick to fix the setting: `set(CXXFLAGS "${CXXFLAGS} -march=native")`